# WPF draw border in container

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to draw area inside a container. For this i thought about using custom control.

My problem is that Canvas does not take up all the given space it gets. How to force it to **use all available space**?

What i have done is inherited from Canvas and created border element inside it:

```
public class DrawableCanvas : Canvas
{
    private Border border;

    static DrawableCanvas()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DrawableCanvas), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DrawableCanvas)));
    }

    public DrawableCanvas()
    {
        this.border = new Border();
        border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
        border.Width = 0;
        border.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        border.Opacity = 0.3;

        this.Children.Add(border);

        this.MouseLeftButtonDown += DrawableCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        this.MouseLeftButtonUp += DrawableCanvas_MouseLeftButtonUp;
        this.MouseMove += DrawableCanvas_MouseMove;
    }

    private void DrawableCanvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Left mouse up");

        // release mouse
        Mouse.Capture(null);

        border.Width = 0;
        border.Height = 100;

        startPosition = 0;
    }

    double startPosition = 0;
    private void DrawableCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Left mouse down");

        border.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        // capture mouse
        Mouse.Capture(this);

        var point = e.GetPosition(this);
        startPosition = point.X;

        SetLeft(border, point.X);
    }

    private void DrawableCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.IsMouseCaptured)
        {
            var point = e.GetPosition(this);

            Debug.WriteLine("Mouse move");

            // set the position to far left
            SetLeft(border, Math.Min(startPosition, point.X));

            // width is the difference between two points
            border.Width = Math.Abs(startPosition - point.X);

            Debug.WriteLine(Math.Min(startPosition, point.X));
            Debug.WriteLine(border.Width);
        }
    }
}
```

And for view:

```
<DockPanel>
    <local:DrawableCanvas>
        <Rectangle Height="500" Width="500" Fill="Transparent" />
    </local:DrawableCanvas>
</DockPanel>
```

I want something like this:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the DockPanel stretches to all that space? Provide more XAML.

Comment: I tried your code with the DockPanel inside a Grid in a Window. The only change I made was `<DockPanel Background="Beige">`. The `DockPanel` fills the `Grid` and the `Grid` fills the window. Please explain why you think you have a problem. Are you confused because the `Border` height is always 100? That's because you set it to that and never change it.

Comment: Try removing rectangle element. Mouse events are not triggered in this case.
I just found out when i set background of canvas to transparent this works. Can you explain why then i will accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted to do is to create this control to enable selection on ui.

For this i needed a border/rectangle that will span only in width and use up all the height it gets

I ended up with this:

**View:**

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf.Test01.Stack_43281567"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf.Test01.Controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Stack_43281567" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <local:DrawableCanvas />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**DrawableCanvas.cs:**

```
public class DrawableCanvas : Canvas
{
    private Border border;

    static DrawableCanvas()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DrawableCanvas), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DrawableCanvas)));
    }

    // when selection is done expose event to notify the user of selection change

    public DrawableCanvas()
    {
        this.border = new Border();
        border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
        border.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        border.Opacity = 0.3;
        border.Height = this.ActualHeight;

        this.Children.Add(border);
        this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);

        this.MouseLeftButtonDown += DrawableCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        this.MouseLeftButtonUp += DrawableCanvas_MouseLeftButtonUp;
        this.MouseMove += DrawableCanvas_MouseMove;

        this.SizeChanged += DrawableCanvas_SizeChanged;
    }

    private void DrawableCanvas_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        border.Height = e.NewSize.Height;
    }

    private void DrawableCanvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Left mouse up");

        // release mouse
        Mouse.Capture(null);

        border.Width = 0;

        startPosition = 0;
    }

    double startPosition = 0;
    private void DrawableCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Left mouse down");

        border.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        // capture mouse
        Mouse.Capture(this);

        var point = e.GetPosition(this);
        startPosition = point.X;

        SetLeft(border, point.X);
    }

    private void DrawableCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsMouseCaptured)
        {
            var point = e.GetPosition(this);

            Debug.WriteLine("Mouse move");

            // set the position to far left
            SetLeft(border, Math.Min(startPosition, point.X));

            // width is the difference between two points
            border.Width = Math.Abs(startPosition - point.X);

            Debug.WriteLine(Math.Min(startPosition, point.X));
            Debug.WriteLine(border.Width);
        }
    }
}
```